# .htaccess redirect works with files not with pages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I use to have the following link in my website:

```
http://mywebsite.com/infoproducts.aspx?xmlname=programCK
```

I changed my server to a linux and installed the wordpress CMS. The new url is:

```
https://mywebsite.com/products/programs/CK
```

I've been using **redirect of files** from previous website to the new one and I had no problem.

```
redirect 301 /downloads/locate.zip http://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/locate.zip
```

However when trying to redirect a page it returns the default 404 error from wordpress.

```
redirect 301 /infoproducts.aspx?xmlname=programCK https://mywebsite.com/products/programs/CK
```

**Note**: The page isn't redirected at all. The 404 error page is from the url `http://mywebsite.com/infoproducts.aspx?xmlname=programCK`

**EDIT 1**: Forgot to mention my `.htaccess` code.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
redirect 301 /downloads/locate.zip https://mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/locate.zip
redirect 301 /infoproducts.aspx?xmlname=programCK https://mywebsite.com/products/programs/CK

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**.

> This answer is only valid for Wordpress CMS.

I removed from `.htaccess` the redirects and installed the plugin **Simple 301 Redirects**. Now everything is working.